# Не работают простейшие View в PopupWindow

Tags: android, popup, view

Раньше создавал уже popup все работало, а на этом минимальном коде нет. Никак не пойму в чем дело, подскажите. Нажатие на кнопку срабатывает, но не работает сама кнопка, т.е. нет анимации нажатия, тоже самое и с editText.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout lay;
    PopupWindow popup;
    Button btnOpenPopup, btnClosePop;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.popupbutton);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup.showAsDropDown(v, 30, 60);
            }
        });

        View window = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        Button b = (Button) window.findViewById(R.id.btnPopup);

        popup = new PopupWindow(window, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btnClosePop = (Button) window.findViewById(R.id.btnPopup);
        btnClosePop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("tag", "pressed");
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Лейаут самый простейший:

POPUP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Close" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

MAIN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drag1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drag2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popupbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Popup" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, в строках

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    popup.showAsDropDown(v, 30, 60);
}
```

не инициализирована переменная popup. Странно, что код работал и не выдавал ошибку.

**UPDATE**

Andreich, согласен, инициализация идёт ниже по тексту. Сегодня тоже долго мучался, нашёл много граблей с этим PopupWindow. В частности, при открытии по кнопке у меня другой код.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (popupWindow == null) {
                // здесь инициализация popupWindow и его отображение.
            }
            if (!popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(txtSomeElement, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: она инициализирована. смотрите внимательней